# Добавить в скрипт JavaScript пустой поиск

Tags: javascript

Нашел в интернете скрипт на Javascript. Что-то типо поисковика. Проблема в том, что при вводе пустого запроса, скрипт отображает все имеющиеся запросы. Как можно сделать так, чтобы скрипт не отображал ничего при вводе пустого запроса?

```html
<!-- 2000 copyright AML development -->

<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Scriptsnetwork ::: ���������������� ������</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">


</HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
A:link   { color: #003399; text-decoration: underline }
A:visited { color:#003399; text-decoration: underline }
A:hover  { color:#003399; text-decoration: none      }
.copy  {  font: 8pt/normal  Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: super; text-decoration: none; color: #333333}
.copy1  {  font: bold 10pt/normal  Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: super; text-decoration: none; color: #333333 }
.copy2  {  font: 9pt/normal  Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: super; text-decoration: none; color: #333333 }

</style>
<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div align="center">
<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.cgi.ru"><img src="topl.gif" width=500 height=29 border=0 alt="Scriptsnetwork"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="copy1" valign="top">
 ���������������� ������!
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="copy2" valign="top">
 <br><br><br>
<script language="javascript">
        var key = "";
        function makeEntry (){
                this.Date = "";
                this.Name="";
                this.URL = "";
                this.Desc = "";
                this.Category = "";
                return this;
        }
 function makeArray(n) {
                this.length = n;
                for (var k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
                                this[k] = "";
                }
                return this;
        }               
        function makeLinks(size) {
                                this.length = size;
                                for (var r=1; r<= size; r++) {
                                                        this[r] = new makeEntry();
                                                        this[r].Date = datesArray[r];
                                                        this[r].Name = namesArray[r];
                                                        this[r].URL = urlsArray[r];
                                                        this[r].Desc = descArray[r];
                                                        }
                                        return this;
                        }
var linksize=0 
datesArray = new makeArray(linksize);
namesArray = new makeArray(linksize);
urlsArray = new makeArray(linksize);
descArray = new makeArray(linksize);
var arraycount=0

/*����� ���������� �������� ������ � ���� */
arraycount += 1 
/* ���� �������� */
datesArray[arraycount] = "1/1/97 "
/* ����� � �������� */
urlsArray[arraycount] = "http://www.yahoo.com"
/* �������� */
namesArray[arraycount] = "Yahoo"
/* �������� */
descArray[arraycount] = "������ � ����� ������� ������� ��������"
/* � ��� ����� */
//alert(arraycount)
arraycount += 1 
datesArray[arraycount] = "1/1/97 "
urlsArray[arraycount] = "http://www.lycos.com"
namesArray[arraycount] = "Lycos"
descArray[arraycount] = "������� ��������� �������"
//alert(arraycount)
arraycount += 1 
datesArray[arraycount] = "1/1/97 "
urlsArray[arraycount] = "http://www.webcrawler.com"
namesArray[arraycount] = "Webcrawler"
descArray[arraycount] = "�������� ���������"
//alert(arraycount)
arraycount += 1 
datesArray[arraycount] = "1/1/97 "
urlsArray[arraycount] = "http://www.search.com"
namesArray[arraycount] = "Search.com"
descArray[arraycount] = "��������� ����� ��������� ������."
//alert(arraycount)
arraycount += 1 
datesArray[arraycount] = "1/1/97 "
urlsArray[arraycount] = "http://altavista.digital.com"
namesArray[arraycount] = "AltaVista"
descArray[arraycount] = "� ���� ��������� ������� ����� ������� ���� ������"
//alert(arraycount)
linksize = arraycount;
// ----end data -------
function showAll(linkobj) {
                for (var s=1; s<= linkobj.length; s++) {
                                               showLink(linkobj,s);
                                }
                        }
function showLink (links, index) {
        //document.write("<table border=1>");
        document.write("<tr><td class='copy2'>" + links[index].Date +"</td>");
        document.write("<td class='copy1'><a href=" + links[index].URL +">" + links[index].Name + "</a></td>");
        document.write("<td class='copy2'>" + links[index].Desc + "</td></tr>");
        //document.write("</table>");
        }
function searchLinks(links, keyword){
        document.write("��������� ������ ���: " +keyword +"<br>");
        document.write("<table>");
        for (var q=1; q<=links.length; q++) {
                        //document.write(q+".")
                        if (links[q].URL.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
                        //      document.write("��������� ������ ���: "+keyword+ "<br>" +links[q].Name +"<p>")
                        //document.write("��������� ������ ���:  "+keyword+ "<br>" );
                                showLink(links,q);
                                continue;
                        }
                        if (links[q].Desc.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
                                        showLink(links,q);
                                continue;
                        }
                        if (links[q].Date.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
                                        showLink(links,q);
                                continue;
                        }
                        if (links[q].Name.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
                                        showLink(links,q);
                                        continue;
                        }
                }
        document.write("</table>");
        }                                       
// final stuff
// the main program ---
jsi = new makeLinks(linksize);
document.write("<title>��������� ������</title><body bgcolor=white>");
searchLinks(jsi, prompt("������� �����:) \r����� � ����:","�����, �����, �����, ����"));
document.write("<hr>");
document.write("����� ���������� �� ���� �������");
document.write("<form><input type=button onClick='history.go(0)' value='������ �����'></form>");
// show all the links
//document.write("<table border>");
//showAll(jsi);
//document.write("</table>");
</script>

 <br><br><br>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="copy" valign="top">
 <hr noshade size="1">
 <a href="http://www.cgi.ru">�������� ��� ������ � ����������� �� ���� ��������!</a>
 <hr noshade size="1">
2000 Copyright &copy <a class="copy" href="http://www.cgi.ru">scriptsnetwork</a>. All rights reserved.<br>
 </td>

</tr>
</table>


</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте на поле ввода .trim() и проверяйте это поле.